# I have a logic, I need the same logic to be written in a batch file (windows). Below is the code

Tags: cmd

The section below is a psuedocode for the logic. I would like to know the batch code for the same.

```
var num = 5;
var total = 45;
for(i = 1; i <= total/num; i++) {   
    for(j = num - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        // copy filename_((num*i) - j) to desitinationFolder/i/
    }
}
```

Basically what this will do is:

- copy filename_1 to filename_5 to destinationFolder/1/
- copy filename_6 to filename_10 to destinationFolder/2/
- copy filename_11 to filename_15 to destinationFolder/3/

and so on...

Comment: I dont know how to write batch programs and not aware of the syntax. but here is a shot:

`for /l %%i in (1,1,%div%) do set ii=%%i & call :for_loop
 goto :for_end

 :for_loop
 set /a j=!num!-1
 
 
 :while_loop
 if !j! geq 0 goto :while_end
  
  set /a source=!num!*!ii!-!j!
  xcopy /i /y !prj!_!source!.* here\!ii!\
  set /a j=j-1
  goto :while_loop
 :while_end
 
goto :eof
:for_end`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As understood from you, you want to transfer 5 files into each folder.
Which means, files 1 to 5 are put into folder 1, 6 to 10 in folder 2, 11 to 15 in folder 3 and so on.

Try out this code, should work well with just one loop.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions

set total=45
set /a result=(total/num1)

set foldernum=0
FOR /L %%I IN (1,1,%total%) DO (
    set /A var=%%I %% 5
    if !var! == 1 (
        set /A foldernum=foldernum + 1
    )
    ECHO %%I And !foldernum!
)
pause
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this out ...

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions

set num1=5
set total=45
set /a result=(total/num1)

FOR /L %%I IN (1,1,%result%) DO (
    FOR /L %%J IN (%num1%, -1, 1) DO (
        set /a curr=%num1%*%%I - %%J
        echo !curr!
    )
)
pause
```

Comment: ok.. how to start from 1 instead of 0 and end at 45 instead of 44?

Comment: Change the line set /a curr=%num1%*%%I - %%J to set /a curr=%num1%*%%I - %%J + 1